# tomcat/hibernate : logging the queries causing the error "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query"

Tags: hibernate, tomcat

The complete error in catalina.out (tomcat 8.5) is :

```
 javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: The transaction has been marked rollback
only because the bean encountered a non-application exception :
javax.persistence.PersistenceException : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
could not execute query
```

This application uses Hibernate 3.3 .
I would like to log the Hibernate sql queries.

I tried this in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties` :

```
handlers = \
    1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
...
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
...
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
...
org.hibernate.level=WARN
org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

at the same time : `-Dhibernate.show_sql=true` as a JVM option.

But I can't find any query in `catalina.out`.
Any help please ?